# Random DNA mix in Solidity

Tags: solidity, random, algorithm

Hello I have DNA mix function and I am trying to implement random function while mixing DNA
for example dad DNA is **10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10** and mum DNA is **21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21** and child DNA should be contain some mum , dad and random numbers for example
**34 10 21 42 21 10 17 10 21 33** here child have some mum DNA some dad DNA and some random.
I wrote this function but random not good working .

```
function _mixDnaX(uint256 _dadDna, uint256 _mumDna)
    internal
    view
    returns (uint256)
{
    uint256 dadPart = _dadDna / 10000000000;
    uint256 mumPart = _mumDna % 10000000000;

    uint256 newDna = (dadPart * 10000000000) + mumPart;


    uint8 random = uint8(block.timestamp % 7) + 1;

    uint256 removeBit = newDna % 100;

    newDna = (newDna - removeBit) + (random * 10) + 1;

    return newDna;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *random not good working*? What output are you expecting and what you got? There's no randomness in `block.timestamp` it will remain constant during the contract execution.

Comment: @Ismael I have already written which result I want above, please read again

Comment: For me the code works, you are mixing _dadDna and _mumDna, only the last two digits are replaced with something "random".